# Does derivative assigns diffrential?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, frechet-derivative

So there are 3 main definitions of derivation in 3 different contexts.

1. **Calculus of one variable real functions.**
   Say we have an everywhere differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
   Then its *derivative is function* $f': \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Its *differential is linear map* $df: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
2. **Functional analysis.**
   Say we have a Banach spaces $E$ and $F$, and a function $f: E \to F$.
   Then for each point $x \in X$ we can define a *Frechet derivative* $f'(x)$ which is a continuous linear map $E \to F$.
   So we have an *assignment* $x \mapsto B(E, F)$.
3. **Manifolds.**
   Say we have manifolds $M$ and $N$ and a morphism $f: M \to N$.
   Then for each point $x \in M$ we can assign a *differential* $df_x$ which is a linear map of tangent spaces $df_x: T_x M \to T_{f(x)} N$.

> Is it true that all of these definitions coincide in the context of
> calculus?

To be more precise:

> So is it true that a derivative is in fact an *assignment* of
> differential to each point? Where differential is morphism of tangent spaces?

I use term *assignment* to emphasize that tangent spaces may be different for each point. It would be beautiful if there is a functor of some sort, but I can't figure it out.

Here are my thoughts:

- There is a distinct notion of derivative and differential in the
  context of calculus, but no differential of function of Banach
  spaces, nor derivative of morphism of manifolds.
- Frechet derivative can be identified with usual derivative because $B(\mathbb{R}, F) \cong F$ (isometric isomorphism).
- Differential of morphisms coincide with usual differential because $T_x \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$.
- So $T_x E \cong E$ for Banach spaces? (Some kind of synthetic-algebraic definition needed here.) Is there a notion of differential forms on Banach spaces, e.g. when doing integrals?
- Is there some geometric structure on tangent spaces? I mean from algebraic view they all have same dimension $T_x M \cong T_y M \cong \mathbb{R}^m$, so we may define a function $f': M \to L(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n)$? (Here $\dim M = m, \dim N = n$.)

Bonus: what about TVS?

Comment: About your first point (I don't know much about manifolds): the Fréchet derivative would correspond to the differential and not the derivative in calculus, thus there is no need for a notion of Fréchet differential that'd be above Fréchet derivative. But there is at least one context where you study a notion that'd correspond to a true derivative: complex-differentiable functions! After all, they are exactly the differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that their differential $df$ is identifiable to a function $f' : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$... 1/2

Comment: ... in such a way that "$df(x)(h) = f'(x) h$" in some sense, thanks to the Cauchy-Riemann equations. The obstacle of defining the multiplication needed for writing "$f'(x) h$" is circumvented by using a [matrix representation of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers), so that "$f'(x) h$" is still in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I won't make it an answer since it's a bit off-topic and I only covered one of your points but hopefully that gave you some food for thought. 2/2

Comment: In your 2. what are $X$ and $B$?

Comment: The wording of item 1. is potentially misleading. The derivative $f'$ is a map from the reals to the reals only in the sense that we identify the target with the space of linear maps from $\mathbf{R}$ to itself, i.e., we interpret the value $f'(x)$ as a _scale factor_ for a copy of the real line (namely, the tangent space to $\mathbf{R}$ at $x$); and then $df(x)$ is multiplication by $f'(x)$ on this tangent space, which is indeed linear. <> Does that help reconcile with 2. and 3.?